# Laravel: Eloquent return results only where relation and relation within that relation exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models: ProductType, ProductSubtype, and ProductSubtypeCategory

**ProductType.php**

```
class ProductType extends Model{
    // A product type has many subtypes
    public function product_subtypes(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductSubtype::class);
    }
}
```

**ProductSubtype.php**

```
class ProductSubtype extends Model{
    // Each product subtype belongs to a type
    public function product_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductType::class);
    }
    // A product subtype has many categories
    public function product_subtype_categories(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductSubtypeCategory::class);
    }
}
```

**ProductSubtypeCategory.php**

```
class ProductSubtypeCategory extends Model{    
    // Each cateogory belongs to a subtype
    public function product_subtype(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductSubtype::class);
    }
}
```

I only want product types where product subtype(s) and subtype category(s) within that subtype exist. So far I have tried this

```
return ProductType::has('product_subtypes', function ($query){
            $query->has('product_subtype_categories');
        })->get();
```

Is there any official way to get the results I want from such nested relations?

Comment: Using `has` is the _"official"_ way as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), but I think you can simplify your query to `ProductType::has('product_subtypes.product_subtype_categories')->get();`

Comment: yeah, that seems to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, but can be simplified.

Change the following:

```
return ProductType::has('product_subtypes', function ($query){
    $query->has('product_subtype_categories');
})->get();
```

to:

```
return ProductType::has('product_subtypes.product_subtype_categories')->get();
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

> When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your
> results based on the existence of a relationship. For example, imagine
> you want to retrieve all blog posts that have at least one comment. To
> do so, you may pass the name of the relationship to the `has` and `orHas`
> methods:

```
// Retrieve all posts that have at least one comment...
$posts = App\Post::has('comments')->get();
```

> Nested `has` statements may also be constructed using "dot" notation.
> For example, you may retrieve all posts that have at least one comment
> and vote:

```
// Retrieve posts that have at least one comment with votes...
$posts = App\Post::has('comments.votes')->get();
```